# Poisson distribution for very large numbers - can i decrease the interval?

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, poisson-distribution

I want to set up a alert notification if transactions on our website fall above or below a low probability number as it could be due to an error.

Lets say i have mean transactions per day of 50,000; and yesterday transactions per day increases to 65,000 - is this normal behaviour or a potential error?

Since the poisson distribution will tend to zero at large numbers, am i allowed to decrease the interval to minutes?

e.g.
50000/(24*60)=35 transactions per minute
65000=(24*60)=45 transaction per minute

therefore poisson probability of 45 transaction per minute is 1.6% which is unlikely so send notification of potential error

And then using the above to make a conclusion on the 65,000 transactions per day to send an error on that?

Comment: It is unclear what you are doing. Your first sentence says "below," but the rest of the question seem to deal with higher values. // Let's start with your assertion in the final sentence: If $X \sim POIS(35),$ then $P(X = 45) = 0.016$ is true, but it seems to me the probability of interest might be $P(X \ge 45) =  0.0585.$

Comment: Thanks. I edited hopefully its more clear now. So I have to look at the cumulative probability rather than just the probability?

Comment: Given enough independent repetitions of an experiment, unlikely events are almost certain to occur.  *E.g.*, an event that occurs in only 1.6% of individual minutes is 95% likely to occur between 14 and 33 times in any day.  Do you really want to be receiving that many *false* alerts daily? This suggests the problem you should be addressing is how to optimize an alert system to meet your needs and constraints, rather than worrying about technical details of Poisson distributions, which--although potentially applicable--may be beside the point.

Comment: whuber, this was just an example. My main question is can I decrease the interval to make a conclusion on the larger interval?